# Calling function with IBAction in another class with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitextview, screenshot

```
class EditTextViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var contentImageView: UIImageView!

        func imageForTextView(UIView) -> UIImage {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(textView.bounds.size, false, 0)

        view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() as UIImage
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//        println(image)
        return image
    }        
}
```

The above code has the function I am trying to call. imageForTextView() takes a screenshot of my textView and turns it into a UIImage.

```
class BackgroundEditTextViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

        @IBAction func instagramButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("yolo")

        EditTextViewController().imageForTextView(EditTextViewController().self.textView)
//        var editTextViewController = EditTextViewController()
//        editTextViewController.imageForTextView(editTextViewController.textView)
    }

}
```

The BackgroundEditTextViewController class is where I am trying to call the "imageForTextView()". When I tap the "instagramButton" to call the "imageForTextView()" I want to see the UIImage printed out in the console. but I keep getting this error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)` I have tried making the "imageForTextView()" a class function but to no avail.

Side note: I have a UIImage behind the textView which I would like to be included in the image screenshot, not too sure how to modify my imageForTextView() to take a screenshot of both the textView & contentImageView. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easy (and not object oriented) way is to share imageForTextView with the world which means to add public before func in that row - it's a trivial solution but it will tell you if your function works properly

```
public func imageForTextView(UIView) -> UIImage
```

the other way is to use a delegate which is to create a function that receives a closure as a parameter that fits imageForTextView's signature like so

```
public func doSomeDelegate((UIView)->UIImage)
```

and then use doSomeDelegate to invoke imageForTextView
that's the general idea

you can find a good explanation in the official swift guide
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

browse to the part that talks about Delegation

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your hierarchy you should use a Custom Delegate or make the function imageForTextView shared.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm quite the noobie.